# tKinter and cv2 GUI - compiled using pyinstaller and freezez when loading video

Tags: python, user-interface, compilation

Trying to compile a simple video player GUI that is built using Tkinter and cv2. After compilation, the GUI opens correctly, but after loading the video file and attempting to play, the GUI freezes.

The compilation is simply done by running the command - 
pyinstaller  in the terminal.

The app works in my python environment prior to the compilation. 
The entire code is published below, for clarity: 
The app uses the cv2 module and PIL to display the video frame by frame in the following way:

1. A frame is loaded using `cv2.VideoCapture(video_source)` method read()
2. The frame is converted to RBG: 
   `cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)`
3. ImageTk isntance is created: 
   `python PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=PIL.Image.fromarray(frame))`
4. loaded to tkinter Fcavas using create_image method. 
   `python Fcanvas.create_image(0, 0, image=self.photo, anchor=NW)`

relevant segments of code is inserted bellow:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog, Label
import PIL.Image, PIL.ImageTk
import cv2
import numpy as np

class Root:
    def __init__(self):
        self.app = Tk()
        self.Fcanvas = Canvas(bg='white', height=1200, width=1200)
        # creating a menu bar
        self.app.mainloop()


    def load_video(self):
        file_name = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir='/', title='Select video')
        self.video_cap = MyVideoCapture(file_name)
        self.Fcanvas = Canvas(bg='white', height=self.video_cap.height, width=self.video_cap.width)
        self.Fcanvas.pack()
        # initiating pause flag
        self.pause_flag = True
        #self.time_bar.config()
        self.time_bar.config(from_=0, to=self.video_cap.vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)/self.video_cap.frame_rate)
        self.time_bar.pack_configure()


    def update(self):
        # check if video object exists
        if self.pause_flag is False:
            try:
                ret, frame = self.video_cap.get_frame()
                if ret:
                    # Get a frame from the video source

                    self.photo = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=PIL.Image.fromarray(frame))
                    self.Fcanvas.delete(ALL)
                    self.Fcanvas.create_image(0, 0, image=self.photo, anchor=NW)
                    self.after_id = self.app.after(int((1 / self.video_cap.frame_rate) * 1000), self.update)
                    # updating timer
                    self.time_print()
                    # updating slider
                    self.time_bar.set(self.video_cap.get_time()/1000)
            except (ValueError, ImportError, AttributeError):
                print('No video was loaded')
                return


class MyVideoCapture:
    def __init__(self, video_source):
        # open the video source
        self.vid = cv2.VideoCapture(video_source)
        if not self.vid.isOpened():
            raise ValueError("Unable to open video source", video_source)
        # get video source width and height
        self.height = self.vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)
        self.width = self.vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
        self.frame_rate = self.vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)

    def get_frame(self):
        if self.vid.isOpened():
            ret, frame = self.vid.read()
            self.cur_frame_cnt = self.vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES)

            if ret:
                # Return a boolean success flag and the current frame converted to BGR
                return ret, cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            else:
                return ret, None
        else:
            return False, None






Root()
```

Comment: to much code ! try to summarize you problem ?

Comment: Are you using -w with the commande pyinstaller to hide the cmd ?

Comment: No, pyinstaller <script name>

Comment: what kind of error are you getting in cmd when you lunch the programe

Comment: No error. The GUI works, the video is simply not loading after compilation. It freezez. (The uncompiled version works)